# PyPDF2 throws error when merging (Python3.3/Win7)

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I'm using PyPDF2 to do a simple merge of PDFs. I wrote the code on XP/Python 3.2 and it works fine. When I moved it to Win7-64bit/Python 3.3 and used the latest PyPDF2 distribution (https://github.com/knowah/PyPDF2/) it throws the following error when appending a PDF to the merger object:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PDFs\pdfmerge2.py", line 103, in <module>
    count=merge_and_check(l_batch_files)
  File "C:\PDFs\pdfmerge2.py", line 47, in merge_and_check
    merger.append(pf)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\merger.py", line 168, in append
    self.merge(len(self.pages), fileobj, bookmark, pages, import_bookmarks)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\merger.py", line 97, in merge
    elif type(fileobj) == file:
NameError: global name 'file' is not defined
```

I've tried clean installs using Python 3.2 and get the same error.

What's weird is that merger.py is very different between my XP install and Win7, but I can't find a reference to an earlier version of PyPDF2 and I can't remember where I downloaded that version from, though I do know it was on 18/12/12. There were no updates to PyPDF2 between then and now from what I can see.

The install on Win7 used the standard 'python setup.py build' then 'install'.

Any ideas?

Comment: This might be useful if you put it on the bug tracker of PyPDF. The programmers of PyPDF may want to know this.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't want to assume it was a defect but I'll let them know.

Comment: I have this error as well. Did you find a solution yet?

Answer (score -1):

Try import io module and then create stream with method FileIO()

example:

```
import io
.
.
.
.
outputStream = io.FileIO('c:\example.pdf', 'wb')
```